# libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, r, ubuntu, rjava, ubuntu-14.10

Trying to install the rJava package on R, on my 14.10 ubuntu, using this code

```
if (!require(rJava)) install.packages('rJava')
```

got few errors related to java including jni problems, after reinstalling the jdk, and tried to run the same code again, got that error

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpfFjrp0/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘rJava’
```

looked for solutions, to find just about everyone suggesting (for x64) to execute those commands

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

but that didn't work, is there anything else I can do? I will provide any needed details

Comment: Yes, but I did try that using the terminal command line and Rstudio command line

Comment: `R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) Rstudio Version 1.2.1335`. In my case, Just quit the `Rstudio` and restart it. I did not redefine the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. ~~~~ 1. run `sudo R CMD javareconf` 2. install my package. 3. restart Rstudio.

Answer (score 29):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to load rJava in RStudio.
The following solution worked for me

```
1) sudo rstudio-server stop
2) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/default
3) sudo rstudio-server start
```

After performing the above steps, I was able to run the following successfuly in RStudio

```
> library("DBI")
> library("rJava")
> library("RJDBC")
```

Comment: This is the only version that worked for me. Or the only answer I could perform competently at least!

Comment: I don't know why but this works for me

Answer (score 28):

To solve this,

1. Run

   > sudo R CMD javareconf
2. Add the following to to /etc/environment. This will then be set every time your machine restarts.

   > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server/

   (change to your path)
3. Run the following:

   > source /etc/environment
4. rstudio server restart

Comment: This one worked for me, not the ones above. Maybe it is necessary to run `R CMD javareconf` as root.

Answer (score 14):

in case none of the above works, try this and thank me later (generic answer) :)

```
R CMD javareconf -e
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Oops.. that didn't work either.  This did.

http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2016/12/rjava-gift-that-keeps-on-giving.html

Answer (score 3):

Check if `$JAVA_HOME` points to the correct location by

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I am using openjdk, however `$JAVA_HOME` was pointing to some non-existing oracle-java folder.

After fixing `$JAVA_HOME` run

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Check the output. `Java headers gen.` should point to `/usr/bin/javah`. For example:

```
djhurio@Skyforger ~ $ sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
Java version     : 11.0.1
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar
```

After this I can install and load `rJava` package.

Answer (score 2):

- I solved a similar issue by running the following command every time I want to open RStudio. Go to the folder which contains the rstudio executable, open up the terminal and type:

  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server: open -a rstudio

  Of course you have to change the path according to your Java version.
- If the previous solution does not work, try reading this article:
  http://allanino.me/blog/programming/installing-some-r-packages/.
- If this solution does not work too, the last chance you have is to install `rJava` compiling it from the source code.

Comment: I have encountered this problem when trying to install a nodejs plug-in that has a java dependency. This no JS app is installed in a Heroku environment. Does anyone have any ideas? if so here is a link to the stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191073/node-java-error-libjvm-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dire

Answer (score 2):

If someone is coming here now, Please try the approach below:

Steps:

1. Find your R location. It will be stored in `rsession-ld-library-path` in `rserver.conf` file. Or just by doing `which R`. The location usually is `/usr/lib64/R/lib` or `/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib`
2. Find the `libjvm.so` file which is usually in the `usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server` path depending on which jre you're using. Check in $JAVA_HOME environment.
3. Create a symlink using `ln -s`
   `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib/libjvm.so`
4. Restart R server

Answer (score 0):

Well, as [@user3673](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871821/user3673) has pointed out [this](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2016/12/rjava-gift-that-keeps-on-giving.html), the solution for me was change the following line in `/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths`:

`: ${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/amd64/server}`

by this one:

`: ${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server}`

Answer (score 0):

We are using AZUL. I could see ZST is not added properly. After adding ZST, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding the answer if we have two R version running on Unix Box.**

**Issue:** libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Caused due to:** Updated the version of java from `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64` to `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64`

In my case, we had two versions of R

1. 3.6.0
2. 3.6.2

we applied the above @minhas23 solution only for 3.6.2 which was set to the default version of R for the Rstudio-server-pro application.

but we were getting a similar error when we select the R version as 3.6.0, then we did the below steps:

```
export R_VERSION=3.6.0

/opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R --version

unlink /usr/local/bin/R

unlink /usr/local/bin/Rscript

ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R
ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/Rscript /usr/local/bin/Rscript

rstudio-server stop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server
R CMD javareconf
```

We have checked the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` associated with `3.6.0` as below in the R terminal:

```
Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
```

O/P

```
[1] "/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for rJava and xlsx in my Dockerfile by searching for the libjvm.so file and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to that directory:

```
RUN find / -name libjvm.so
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server
```