# rJava linker error licuuc with Anaconda & fopenmp error without Anaconda for macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: r, macos, homebrew, macos-sierra, rjava

I want to install rJava on macOS Sierra 10.12.4. My current Java version is `Java version: 1.8.0_131`, according to `R CMD javareconf|grep version`. I have installed Java with Homebrew's cask.

My Java runs the following

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

My R version is

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2 (64-bit)
```

R Java config runs such that

```
$ R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_131
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
clang -I/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin -I/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/include    -fPIC  -I/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/include  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/lib/R/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/lib -lgfortran -L/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -L/Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -liconv -lc -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Volumes/osx/201705_anaconda/anaconda/lib/R
Done.
```

which looks to be properly set-up as guided [here](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/36#issuecomment-121871755) and this SO thread [unable to compile JNI program rJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570586/unable-to-compile-jni-program-rjava) so the JDK looks to be correctly installed.

I get the linker error with the command `install.packages("rJava")`

```
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin'
java libs   : '-L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm'
...
ld: library not found for -licuuc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
```

I have got the same error despite Java sources: official JDK and Homebrew's Java return the same linker/library error.

### **What could be causing this linker/library licuuc error with Anaconda and how to fix it?**

*Old threads*

1. [Install rJava on macOS Sierra 10.12.1: linker error licuuc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572179/install-rjava-on-macos-sierra-10-12-1-linker-error-licuuc): a solution candidate with MacPorts
2. [rJava on MacOS Sierra 10.12.15: unsupported option fopenmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383668/rjava-on-macos-sierra-10-12-15-unsupported-option-fopenmp)
3. [rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)
4. [Install xlsx and rJava on macOS Mavericks 10.9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755013/install-xlsx-and-rjava-on-macos-mavericks-10-9-5)

**Fixes that I have tried**

1. `options("java.home")` returns NULL so `options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/")` as guided by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30738974/164148)
2. Unistalled Homebrew's Java and replaced it with Oracele's Java and JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html): the same licuuc library/linker error persists. I tried `sudo Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")'` guided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640416/164148) but the same `licuuc library not found` error.
3. Updated macOS from El Capitan 10.11.6 to Sierra 10.12.4 but the same licuuc library/linker error persists.
4. *Running without sudo, javac missing (following this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488810/164148) and this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42009476/164148)). This error may be easiest to fix with pointing the javac directory there to `/usr/bin/javac` but better solution? When I run it with sudo, I got the same licuuc error.*

   ```
   R CMD javareconf -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH

   Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")'

   Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/javac"
   (-1)
       make[2]: *** [org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.class] Error 2
       make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
       make: *** [jri] Error 2
       ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
   ```
5. After removal of Anaconda `conda install anaconda-clean; anaconda-clean --yes; rm -rf ~/anaconda`, guided [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall), and installing R with cask such that `brew cask install r-app; sudo R CMD javareconf; Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")'` so getting a new error

   ```
   clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
   make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
   make: *** [jri] Error 2
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
   ```

### **What could be causing this error forenmp without Anaconda and how to fix it?**

Comment: `201705_anaconda/anaconda` you are using anaconda to manage your _R_ install instead of `brew cask`? Switch that.

Comment: @coatless I removed Anaconda `conda install anaconda-clean; anaconda-clean --yes; rm -rf ~/anaconda` and `brew install r`. Restarted the terminal but `$ R CMD javareconf
/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1/lib/R/bin/Rcmd: line 62: exec: javareconf: not found`, ideas? Did your paths get automatically set up with brew R installation?

Comment: Install _R_ via `brew cask r-app`. Using `brew install r` is going to give you something less than what you desire. Secondly, where is `java` from?

Comment: @coatless current version is from Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) with JDK but I can do everything with brew if that is the easiest.

Comment: Did you try re-running through the `R CMD javareconf` with the new R-app version of R?

Comment: Another error that I can think of is xcode cli not being installed (e.g. `xcode-select --install`), but I don't think that's the case...

Comment: @coatless Yes, I have done `xcode-select --install` and installed the `brew cask install r-app` so `sudo R CMD javareconf` started working again. A new error `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'` and no licuuc error anymore so related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383668/rjava-on-macos-sierra-10-12-15-unsupported-option-fopenmp) potentially.

Comment: Heh. That's an easy error to fix... See http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/ and https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-clang

Comment: @coatless It may be easy but it is taking ages to compile this `brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49 --without-multilib` from the [blog](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/), still on `make bootstrap`, now about 1 hour lasted to run it :/

Comment: stupid question maybe, but do you have libicuuc (bundled in brew formula icu4c)?

Comment: @Ian icu4c is installed on my system, it is not the issue to this error. I found the reason to be Anaconda Path: I just removed the Anaconda path from my ~/.bash_profile as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134672/164148) and I got `rJava` installed even with Anaconda.

Comment: @coatless we are having problems with the gcc setup in MLR, bug reported  [here](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/1903#issuecomment-316232995), any clue what could cause such a malbehaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I provide the solution in two ways: Anaconda and the Brew way. I suggest you to use the Brew solution. In both cases, I have Oracle's JDK installed and if you do this, remember reconfigure Java for R with `sudo R CMD javareconf`.

**Anaconda (solution to the licuuc error)**

A similar linker error occurred [here](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/333/osx-1011-install-linker-error-library-not). The anaconda path messes things up as

```
$ R CMD config --ldflags
  -L/Users/osx/anaconda3/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
```

so remove a path like below from `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/Users/osx/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" #Removed to install rJava
```

so we should get something like

```
$ R CMD config --ldflags
  -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv
```

and after this rJava can be installed even with Anaconda with

```
sudo R CMD javareconf 
Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")'
```

congratulations!

**Brew (solution to fopenmp error)**

Your R installation should be done with Homebrew cask such that

```
brew cask install r-app
```

where brew's r package is not enough for this. Shortly, the forenmp problem is in the compiler not having the flag so we have to recompile the compiler. This solution is explained more thoroughly [here](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/). The problem in the question is for 3.3.* R and gcc solution used such that

```
#xcode-select --install #if Xcode commandline tools not installed
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49 --without-multilib #Long ~70min compiling...
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
brew link --overwrite --force gcc49
brew unlink gcc49 && brew link gcc49
brew install llvm
mkdir ~/.R; touch ~/.R/Makevars

echo "VER=-4.9 
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CXX1X=g++$(VER)
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.3/lib/gcc/4.9" > ~/.R/Makevars
```

and now

```
sudo R CMD javareconf 
Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")'
```

and now `rJava` is working!

*Solutions here mentioned also in the following because of similar problems*

1. [Install rJava on macOS Sierra 10.12.1: linker error licuuc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572179/install-rjava-on-macos-sierra-10-12-1-linker-error-licuuc)
2. [rJava on MacOS Sierra 10.12.15: unsupported option fopenmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383668/rjava-on-macos-sierra-10-12-15-unsupported-option-fopenmp)

Comment: Hi thanks for writing the solution! My homebrew is saying "Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated." on running the first command. Any idea how to get around this?